# candyMachine.itemRemaining is BigNumber instead of number

Tags: web3.js, metaplex, metaplex-js, candy-machine-v3

I'm creating a function to tell the content of a candy machine and running into the issue that items remaining is in BigNumber instead of number. I want to show if zero items remaining then say the candy machine is sold out. Also, use it in the onClick function in the return.

```
import { CandyMachine } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";

const getFreeMintButtonContent = () => {
  if (!candyMachine) {
    return "Loading...";
  }

  if (isUserMinting) {
    return "Minting in progress..";
    // candyMachine.itemsRemaining is a bigNumber and === 0 is a number so there is conflict //
  } else if (candyMachine.itemsRemaining === 0) {
    return "Sold out";
  } else {
    return "FREE";
  }
};

return (

<div className={styles.mintButton}>
              <Button onClick={async () => await freeMintButtonClicked()} disabled={isUserMinting || candyMachine?.itemsRemaining === 0}>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" style={{
                    fontSize: "16px",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    color: "white",
                    textAlign: "center",
                  }}>
                  { getFreeMintButtonContent() }
                </Typography>
              </Button>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `Number(candyMachine.itemsRemaining)` for the check in your frontend